# building router handler: building TLS config: invalid certificate(s) content

Tags: openshift, traefik, traefik-routers

i am trying to load the tls certificates for one of my traefik routers. the path in the `certFile` and `keyFile` is the path to a volume mount on my container that contains the secrets with the certificates inside

here is my router config toml file

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.router1]
    rule = "PathPrefix(`/path1`)"
    middlewares = ["middleware1"]
    service = "service1"
    entryPoints = ["web-secure"]
  [http.routers.router2]
    rule = "PathPrefix(`/path2`)"
    middlewares = ["middleware2"]
    service = "service2"
    entryPoints = ["web-secure"]
  [http.routers.router3]
    rule = "Path(`path3`)"
    middlewares = ["middleware3"]
    service = "service"
    entryPoints = ["web-secure"]

[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/app/pki/etc/webserver_cert.crt"
  keyFile = "/app/pki/etc/webserver_cert.key"
```

however when i check my logs on openshift, it gives me the following error for all our routers
`{"entryPointName":"web-secure","level":"error","msg":"building router handler: building TLS config: invalid certificate(s) content","routerName":"router2@file","time":"2023-07-12T02:21:48Z"}`

i referenced this documentation to create dynamic tls config within the router, but not sure why it is not registering the certificate https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v1-to-v2/#tls-configuration-is-now-dynamic-per-router

path in the `certFile` and `keyFile` is correct and the certificates are in the right format as well, so im not sure what other potential problems could've caused this error

Comment: How were the certificates generated? How have you verified their content?

Comment: @larsks the certs are generated by another team within the company and they have verified that the content is accurate. is there any other possible reason as to why such an issue would occur?